# shopify product grid clearfix

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

For my product grid, the clearfix is automatically setting the height to 80px. BUT then, when you click on the collection link again, it displays correctly.

why would this happen? is there some kind of cashe in shopify?

Comment: link is -- www.deekeller.com passowrd is pink 1111

Comment: It looks like there's JavaScript somewhere that's trying to set the height of those boxes, I'm guessing based on the height of each box's contents...but sometimes the JavaScript fires before the box's content loads, which is why sometimes the height is 80px and sometimes it's correct. Is this your JavaScript code, or Shopify's?

Comment: it's the theme's code...so shopify i guess. The theme is called "new standard". but here's the catch...I (stupid) have edited it! and I guess I messed this up? @pjmccormick any idea what i should do?

Comment: @PJMcCormick whoops i didn't tag your name correctly

Comment: So, it looks like the code that should be formatting the image heights is in shop.js, lines 486-501, but comparing your source code with the [theme's demo](http://the-new-standard-theme.myshopify.com/collections/boots), I'm having trouble pinpointing why yours isn't working. What files did you edit? Did you change the JS files or the theme's base HTML? Also, have you reached out to Shopify about this? It looks like they officially support this theme, although I'm not sure what their turn-around time is.

Comment: @PJMcCormick yes, that's the problem! the turnaround time is horrible. but yes I edited the HTML and the JS files (uh oh). Because I wanted to change the width of the site to make it larger....which necessitated me changing all those files. i wish i wasn't so helpless, but i feel like i've tried everything and reached out to everyone possible! no idea what to do now

Comment: @PJMcCormick i can't tell you how thankful I am for your help

Comment: if (IS_COLLECTION_LISTING) {

    /* Preload and Format Images */
    loadImages('#collection-list .four-per-row img',FOUR_PER_ROW_H);
    loadImages('#collection-list .three-per-row img',THREE_PER_ROW_H);

    var golden_height = 0;
    $('#collection-list li').each(function(i){
        if ($(this).height() > golden_height) {
            golden_height = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    $('#collection-list li').css('height',golden_height);

} // END of IS_COLLECTION_LISTING

Comment: Let's do some backtracking and see if we can pinpoint the issue. Save your edited version of shop.js and then replace it with Shopify's original shop.js, [which you can get here](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0147/8382/t/15/assets/shop.js?3706). Things will probably still be kind of messed up, but we need to see if at least the images fading in work...

Comment: @PJMcCormick ok did that! and it doesn't look like there's any difference?